# how can I stage a single line in SmartGit?

Tags: smartgit

I want to stage a single line in SmartGit, rather than a whole diff hunk.

Eg:

```
old line
new line but leave unstaged
new line, just stage this
new line but leave unstaged
new line but leave unstaged
old line
```

This is doable with GitX on OS X but on SmartGit the smallest unit I appear to be able to stage is a whole set of diff lines.

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24386597/492

Answer (score 15):

Use **Local|Index Editor**: you can edit the Index file content as you like there.

Comment: How? I have the index editor open right now in front of me and I can see how to stage a *hunk* but not how to stage a single line.

Comment: Oh, I see. You have to actually select the line, copy from right RHS pane and click and paste it into the middle one. That's pretty lousy UI, as that's not actually staging a change but manually reproducing it in the index.

Comment: I agree. SourceTree has a "stage selected line(s)" function in the context menu of a single line.

Comment: @StevenRoose, there is a much simpler procedure in more recent versions of SmartGit, see my updated answer.

Comment: @mstrap I don't think the problem is how to use SmartGit's hunk features, but how to stage *part of* a hunk. SmartGit decides what a hunk is (basically any consecutive lines of new code) and there seems to be no way to override that if you only want part of that hunk for a commit.

Comment: @neverfox, you are right -- I didn't reread the question carefully these 1.5 years later after my first answer. I changed the answer back.

Comment: Awesome feature! Staging selected lines would be useful, though.

Answer (score 7):

As of version 4.5 and later, you can simply select the file, and in Changes view, right click the line > Stage Hunk (OR) Stage Inner-line Changes (if you right click the highlighted change).

Comment: It is missing in 17.1 if the older version is detected as binary (due to a long line), even if you press "force text"