# How do I only commit specific lines using SmartGit/Hg

Tags: git, version-control, commit, staging, smartgit

I'm using SmartGit/Hg. I edited some files working on two separate new features. Now as I finished working on **Feature A**, I want to commit my work, but I can't just commit all my edited files, as they contain changes of **Feature B**, which I do not want to commit just now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can achieve that using the [stage](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/119790) command. First of all, *stage* all the files containing changes to be committed. In this example, all the files except the one called `DoNotCommit.php` contain at least one line we want to commit:[image]

Next, we need to open the *Index Editor* for all files containing lines of **Feature A** *and* **Feature B**. In this example, we need to check `Main.php` and `NewFeatures.php`:[image]

This opens the *Index Editor*. You see three tabs with your code: *Repository (HEAD)*, *Index*, *Working Tree*:[image]

For us, only the *Repository (HEAD)* and the *Index* tab are important. The *Repository (HEAD)* tab shows the already committed content of the file. The *Index* tab shows the changes we are going to commit. Let's say we only want to commit the first block of code, with the `myNewCompletedFeature` function:[image]

As you see, we remove all the code we do not want to commit from the **Index** tab. This does **not** remove the code from the *Working Tree*, meaning you do not loose any of your changes. Now we do the same with our new `NewFeatures.php` file and save again:[image]

In the last step, we are going to actually commit the new feature. **Make sure to select *Staged Changes* in the commit window!**[image]

Wow, we are done now!

Comment: Cool Explanation with animated Gifs!

Comment: Quite possibly the clearest answer I have even seen on SO.